# Unable to change default margins in Word 2013

Tags: microsoft-word-2013

The following is the default Page Setup for my version of Word 2013

[image]
[image]
[image]

My goal is to have an A4-sized document with the following margins:

**Top: 3cm**

**Left: 3cm**

**Bottom: 2cm**

**Right: 2cm**

However, whenever I try to change margin values, the following message pops up:

[image]

In a Microsoft forum, the following solution seems to have worked for many who use Word 2010:

*"Go to Page Layout | Page Setup | Columns | More Columns... In the Columns dialog, click the preset picture for One (even though the document is already formatted for one column). This will check the "Equal column width" check box, which allows a single column to be resized to fit margin width as margins are changed. A bug in setting columns sometimes leaves this box unchecked (and there's no way to check it directly when you have only one column), resulting in a column that is too wide for the margins and doesn't adjust automatically."*

Nonetheless, as aforestated, my version of Word is 2013's. As shown on images, there is no **Columns** setting in the Page Setup window. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Look closely, the columns button should be there in word 2013: [screenshot1](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Create-newsletter-style-columns-86744130-b87d-4ee0-a930-4163e732b84a) [screenshot2](https://www.google.ru/imgres?imgurl=http%3A%2F%2Fcontent.gcflearnfree.org%2Ftopics%2F233%2Fcolumns_undo.png&imgrefurl=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.gcflearnfree.org%2Fword2013%2Fcolumns%2F1%2F&docid=W9HLgJtksh-4KM&tbnid=iDhlmflajfmYAM%3A&w=372&h=353&bih=767&biw=1173&ved=0ahUKEwjWhtWNw_7NAhWIDiwKHTrPCDEQMwgcKAAwAA&iact=mrc&uact=8). After finding it just follow the instruction you posted. That should help you if you actually changed paper format or paper orientation before altering the margins.

However, if portrait A4 is the default like you said, and the only thing you changed were margins, you may be actually printing to something wierd like a barcode printer. Try selecting the printer you wish to print to before setting the margins.

If you do not have a physical printer try selecting XPS printer. If you do not have that either try installing virtual printer software like "doPDF" or something like that.

This may also happen if you enter the wrong number format like `2.0cm` instead of `2,0cm`. Try typing just `2` without `cm` or anything in a field and hit <kbd>Ok</kbd>

Hope that helps